# react-hook-forms validating image extension is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I am working on ReactJs (version 18) with `react-hook-form`.

I have a form with text and file inputs and I am trying to validate image extension. Everything is working fine expect image extension.

Required validations is working fine but when I upload invalid image such as .svg or .webp it doesn't validating it.

> **Note:** i am using `useRef()` hook to select a file/image

I have no idea what i am doing wrong.
Please correct me. Thanks!

```js
const { loader, errorMessage } = useSelector(state => state.auth);

const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
const profileImgRef = useRef(null);
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
    avtarFullName: yup.string().required('Name is required'),
    avtarGender: yup.string().required('Gender is required'),
    avtarProfileImage: yup.mixed()
        .required('Please upload an image')
        .test('fileType', 'Only image files with extensions jpeg, jpg, png, or mpeg are allowed', (value) => {
            if (!value || !value[0]) {
                return true; // no file uploaded, validation passed
            }
            console.log(value)
            const fileExtension = value[0].name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            const validTypes = ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'mpeg'];

            const fileType = fileExtension;
            return validTypes.includes(fileType);
        }),

});

const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, setValue, setError, trigger } = useForm({
    mode: 'onChange',
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
    defaultValues: {
        avtarProfileImage: null
    }
});

const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log("=>>>", data);
};

const handleProfileImgChange = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log("file", file);
    setFile(file);
    setValue('avtarProfileImage', (e) => {
        const newValue = e.target.files[0];
        // perform validation here if needed
        return newValue;
    });
    trigger('avtarProfileImage');

};
```

**My Form**

```js
<div className="box-body">
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" {...register('avtarFullName')} name="avtarFullName" placeholder="Avtar name" className="form-control" />
        {errors.avtarFullName && <p className='error-message'>{errors.avtarFullName.message}</p>}
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-6 mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="">Gender</label>
        <select {...register('avtarGender')} name="avtarGender" className="form-control">
          <option value="" >Please select gender</option>
          <option value={ENUM_AVTAR.GENDER.MALE}>Male</option>
          <option value={ENUM_AVTAR.GENDER.FEMALE}>Female</option>
        </select>
        {errors.avtarGender && <p className='error-message'>{errors.avtarGender.message}</p>}

      </div>
      <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="">Upload Image</label>
        <div onClick={() => profileImgRef.current.click()} className="drop-zone">
          <span className="drop-zone__prompt">Drop file here or click to upload</span>
          <input
            {...register('avtarProfileImage')}
            ref={profileImgRef}
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            name="avtarProfileImage"
            className=""
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            onChange={handleProfileImgChange}
          />
        </div>
        {errors.avtarProfileImage && <p className='error-message'>{errors.avtarProfileImage.message}</p>}
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
        <input type="checkbox" name="private" /> Private
      </div>
      <div className="col-md-12 mt-4">
        <button disabled={loader} className="btn primary-btn">{loader ? 'Please Wait...' : 'Create'}</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```